# Gretl - how to compute a matrix

Tags: statistics, linear-regression, gretl

i have a linear regression model:

```
yi = α + βxi + ui
```

and I want to compute:

```
(\sigma_u)^2(X'X)^(-1)
```

Can I do that in gretl and how?
If not, how to get the X matrix out of gretl?

I really appreciate your reply!!!

Comment: What does this have to do with R?

Comment: @thelatemail gretl is a R package!!!

Comment: No gretl is not, check here http://gretl.sourceforge.net/

Comment: There is also a mailing list, you will get more support there http://lists.wfu.edu/mailman/listinfo/gretl-users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one approach. If you want to learn more I urge you to read the chapter 13 of the [gretl guide](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://ricardo.ecn.wfu.edu/pub//gretl/manual/en/gretl-guide-a4.pdf&sa=U&ei=mbxrUcecDcimPfXjgaAL&ved=0CBgQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNG0JUoQNIzHJLlA1SKPt4H4WDcGPg).

```
open galton
list xlist = const parent child # or list xlist 0 1 2 
matrix X = {xlist}
ols const child parent --quiet
scalar sigma_u = $sigma
matrix res = sigma_u^2 * inv(X'X)
res

##  res
## res (3 x 3)

##    0.0010799  -1.2533e-05  -3.2771e-06 
##  -1.2533e-05   2.7165e-07  -8.8464e-08 
##  -3.2771e-06  -8.8464e-08   1.3688e-07
```

Answer (score 2):

dickoa: I supposse your response wanted to be:

```
open galton
list xlist = const parent # or list xlist 0 1 2 
matrix X = {xlist}
ols child const parent --quiet
scalar sigma_u = $sigma
matrix res = sigma_u^2 * inv(X'X)
res
```

In any case, it is even an easier way to do this:

```
open galton
list xlist = const parent # or list xlist 0 1 2 
matrix X = {xlist}
ols child const parent --quiet
matrix res = $vcv
res
```